# Is it Jupiter Only a Gas Giant?

Tags: planet, jupiter

i heard & saw in website & you tube most of the people saying that i Jupiter planet made of Gas..i like to know if we some how went to Jupiter & land a Space Ship cant we find a Hard Land with soil.

Comment: Use standard grammar and spelling to ask questions. It is polite to do this.

Comment: @RANSARA009 James is just politely trying to guide you to follow the community rules: ["Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability."](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) and ["Be specific. If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you continue to ignore the system and [act rude](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), you might have to be suspended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can't land in the usual sense. You just sink into the gas and will be destroyed by the high pressure at some point. In fact deep inside the gas may be even denser than the ship and so the ship will tend to float. Anyway if you really want to "land", then assuming that somehow your ship survives all the adverse conditions and you have an engine to oppose the upthrust and to pass through the metallic hydrogen mantle, you will finally "land" at the solid core of the planet.

Comment: Now that would take some engineering.